# fruitful questions that yield highly scored answers. Should they keep with 0 upvotes?

Tags: discussion

During review I have found some questions with no or one upvote that however produced fruitful discussions or a series of answers, one or more of them with a high number of votes.

Personally, if I find a correct, non-voted question with answers with 5-10 or more upvotes I automatically upvote the question.

What people think about this? Should these questions get recognized in some way?

Comment: If, the question is good upvote it.  If a bad question has a good answer upvote the answer, not the question.  Except, if I *search for a specific problem* and find an answer that I upvote, I usually upvote the question too.

Answer (score 5):

Not on how many answers a question gets, but on how good the question itself is.

I consider it a smell if a question produces many upvoted answers, but does not have upvotes itself.

Comment: You are right, I agree, but note that I was talking about correct questions, at least as correct as the corresponding answers. My perceived fact is that answers tend to be more upvoted than questions.  Also there is probably a psycological bias that drives  people to upvote more heavily answers and questions from posters with higher reputation. My opinion is that brilliant answers are difficult to derive from a bad question. So that these situations also smell for me. That was the point of my question :-)